# Operator '<' cannot be applied to operands of type 'bool' and 'double'

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

Wow...I've never seen this before. Any way to get around it?

```
foreach( double r in portfolioReturns)
        {
            if (-8.0 < r < -7.0)
            {
                n8++;
            }}
```

Comment: bonus piggyback question: which languages actually do allow this?

Comment: I sincerely hope you don't format your braces like that in production code.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4090845/language-support-for-chained-comparison-operators-x-y-z lists some that have similar support: Python, Perl 6, Mathematica, Scheme, BCPL, Icon.

Comment: [CoffeeScript](http://coffeescript.org/#comparisons), too.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are effectively doing this

```
if ((-8.0 < r) < -7.0)
```

Since (-8.0 < r) evaluates to a boolean, you can't compare it to a float. Do this instead:

```
if (-8.0 < r && r < -7.0) {
  //code here
}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
if (-8.0 < r && r < -7.0)
```

Answer (score 3):

let me guess, you are coming from python? It is the only language I know of where that works :-)

looking at `(-8.0 < r < -7.0)`, first, -8.0 < r gets evaluated, which is true. true < -7.0 barfs.

Answer (score 3):

You could also use LINQ, in addition to the fix everyone so quickly provided

```
n8 += portfolioReturns.Count(r => -8.0 < r && r < -7.0);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach(double r in portfolioReturns)
{
    if(-8.0 < r && r < -7.0)
            n8++;
}
```