# Language support for chained comparison operators (x < y < z)

Tags: programming-languages, syntax, operators

A [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4089284/why-does-0-5-3-return-true/) was posted about chained comparison operators and how they are interpreted in different languages.

Chaining comparison operators means that `(x < y < z)` would be interpreted as `((x < y) && (y < z))` instead of as `((x < y) < z)`.

The comments on that question show that Python, Perl 6, and Mathematica support chaining comparison operators, but what other languages support this feature and why is it not more common?

A quick look at the Python documentation shows that this feature has been since at least 1996.  Is there a reason more languages have not added this syntax?

A statically typed language would have problems with type conversion, but are there other reasons this is not more common?

Comment: Good question. It seems to me that it would even be backward compatible for Java at least. (Since `<` and `>` are not defined for booleans.)

Comment: I think it's not common because programmers are too used to `<` being a binary operator.

Comment: Why would statically typed languages have problems with this? What type conversions do you mean?

Comment: Java for example returns a boolean from a comparison operator.  This syntax would then be comparing a boolean to another type like int, which is not defined.  You need some type of dynamic typing that allows comparison operators on booleans.

Comment: No, you don't need dynamic typing. First, static typing doesn't prevent operators on booleans. Second, even if it did, this feature doesn't require `<` and `>` on booleans, it requires the compiler to rewrite `x > y < z` to `x > y and y < z`. You can't solve this by defining `<` and `>` on booleans - but since those aren't defined anyway (that would be nonsensical), this feature could be added to e.g. Java without breaking existing code that tries to order boolean.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I was combining the issues incorrectly.  It still makes me wonder why this is not more common syntax.

Comment: @user395760 what's nonsensical about `bool < bool`? `false` being smaller than `true` is perfectly reasonable

Comment: Chained comparison operators are now supported in Perl 5.32.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It should be more common, but I suspect it is not because it makes parsing languages more complex.

Benefits:

- Upholds the principle of least surprise
- Reads like math is taught
- Reduces cognitive load (see previous 2 points)

Drawbacks:

- Grammar is more complex for the language
- Special case syntactic sugar

As to why not, my guesses are:

- Language author(s) didn't think of it
- Is on the 'nice to have' list
- Was decided that it wasn't useful enough to justify implementing

Comment: How "math is taught" is not necessarily a benefit.  How mathematical ideas are taught and even how they are written down often does not reflect proper underlying ideas.  It is more common for lay people to try programming now-a-days, but really in-depth programming eventually requires a better understanding of functional notations and concepts (e.g. lambda expressions). The proper interpretation (i.e. reading) of "x < y < z" has always been "x is less than y AND y is less than z", so it shouldn't be that problematic to just require programming to be as explicit.

Comment: Disagree with "Upholds the principle of least surprise"  : one of the things that attracted me to C in the first place was that every expression had the same meaning regardless of context.  `a < b` always results in a `1` or `0` regardless of context. No surprises .  It would increase cognitive load to have `a < b` sometimes being the binary `<` operator, and sometimes being part of a ternary operator that consists of a `<` sign and some later `<` (or `>` and so on)

Comment: M.M, that's true but the fact that a < b reduces to 0 or 1 is a behind-the-scenes implementation detail. Conceptually it is a boolean not a numeric value, so for higher level languages the 0 or 1 is not present as a possible interpretation. Still, if a < b is boolean, what would "true < c mean", where c is integer? Nothing really. So chaining could be fine for higher level languages.

Comment: @brucearmstrong: one other important  benefit is the number of times the middle operand it evaluated.

Answer (score 11):

The benefit is too small to justify complicating the language.

You don't need it that often, and it is easy to get the same effect cleanly with a few characters more.

Comment: Added complexity seems like a poor reason.  I cannot think of a reason that the current functionality would be useful in a dynamically typed language, while this would add extra functionality without much conflict.  It also seems to me that it is easier to read.

Comment: I tend to agree. It's neat one in a million times, but it sure takes a lot of hassle to implement and incorporate into the grammer.

Comment: @Alan You mustn't think of it that way. Instead you have to turn it around, what do you gain, compared to the work needed to spec, document, plan, implement and test it?

Comment: @Alan: As for the vote for complexity: what other features would "expect" to have the feature (e.g. custom overloaded operators), and how complicated is it to get them to work unambiguously? Does it introduce potential parsing ambiguity (ala C++'s `std::list<std::list<int>>` problem)? Do you expect it to short-circuit evaluations (`foo(value) < b < bar(value)` - does bar get called if `foo(value) < b` is false?), and why or why not? There is a *lot* of investigation that needs to be done to support any new language feature, especially ones that aren't commonly implemented in popular languages.

Comment: Currently popular languagess have trash syntax inherited from C. There were/are many languages that support chained comparisons so theres no need for reinventing the wheel.

Comment: `((x < y) && (y < z))` vs `(x < y < z)`: adds 6 characters to an 11-character expression (including spaces). That's more than a 50% increase. How is that "a few"?

Comment: *Nine* characters. I can't do math, apparently >_<

Comment: @starblue I need it quite often

Comment: @Malcolm that would not be the only reason. what is problematic is that y is evaluated twice in the `&&` case and only once in the ternary version. Quit a difference and certainly no syntactic sugar!

Comment: @theking2 That only makes a difference if evaluating `y` has side effects, which I hope will be extremely rare (it's almost always bad style).

Comment: @starblue ...or if `y` is expensive to evaluate. Of course, you could evaluate it beforehand and assign the result to a variable...but then that's even more additional characters you have to write & read. Chained comparison might not always be worth implementing, but "it's never worth it" is definitely wrong.

Answer (score 5):

Scheme (and probably most other Lisp family languages) supports multiple comparison efficiently within its grammar:

```
(< x y z)
```

This can be considered an ordinary function application of the `<` function with three arguments. See [6.2.5 Numerical Operations](http://www.schemers.org/Documents/Standards/R5RS/HTML/r5rs-Z-H-9.html#%_sec_6.2.5) in the specification.

Clojure supports [chained comparison](http://clojure.github.com/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/%3C) too.

Answer (score 4):

Chained comparison is a feature of BCPL, since the late 1960s.

Answer (score 1):

I think ICON is the original language to have this, and in ICON it falls out of the way that booleans are handled as special 'fail' tags with all other values being treated as true.