# 100 <= x <= 150 as argument in if (), acting funny

Tags: objective-c, c, algorithm, if-statement, conditional-statements

I have an `if` statement followed by several `else if` statements. All of the if/else if statements have an argument structured something like this:

```
if (100 <= x <= 149) //do this
else if (150 <= x <= 199) //do that
else if ...etc...
```

However, for some reason only the first if statement ever gets executed. X can be 200 and only the first if statement will be recognized.

I'm not sure why it isn't moving on to the next else if statement when X doesn't fit the argument of the preceding statement. Does this not work in Obj-C? Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: there are a lot of duplicates: [Language support for chained comparison operators (x < y < z)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4090845/995714), [Why can't I just use 51 <= j <= 55? / data types (duplicate)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54168808/995714), [100 <= x <= 150 as argument in if (), acting funny](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9014701/995714), [Is (val1 > val2 > val3) a valid comparison in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38643022/995714)...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Language support for chained comparison operators (x < y < z)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4090845/language-support-for-chained-comparison-operators-x-y-z)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to rephrase the statements like:

```
if (x >= 100 && x <= 149) {
} else if (x >= 150 && x <= 199) {
} ...
```

Your first `if` is evaluated like:

```
if ((100 <= x) <= 149)
```

Let's have a look how that evaluates:

- If `x = 200`, then `(100 <= 200)` is true and thus evaluates to the value `1` (which means true). And then `1 <= 149` is also true.
- If `x` has a value smaller than 100, for example `10`, then `(100 <= 10)` is false and thus evaluates to the value `0` (which means false). Again, `0 <= 149` is true.

So regardless of the value of `x`, the whole expression will always be true.

Answer (score 12):

C is not math, so

```
if (100 <= x <= 149)
```

is NOT the same as

```
if (100 <= x &&  x <= 149)
```

Which is what you meant. The former will be true always, because `100 <= x <= 149` becomes

```
((100 <= x) <= 149)
```

leaving two possibilities:  `(1 <= 149)` or `(0 <= 149)`. Both are always true.

Comment: +1, I overlooked that the expression is also true if the first part evaluated false.

Answer (score 4):

Chained comparisons like these don't work in C-based languages. Or rather, they do, but not how you'd expect.

`100 <= x <= 149` gets evaluated as `(100 <= x) <= 149`. If `x` is over 100, then `(100 <= x)` will evaluate to true, or `1`. If `x` is under 100, it's false, or `0`. In either case, `0 <= 149` or `1 <= 149` is true, so the overall expression is true.

To fix this, change your conditions to look like this:

```
if (100 <= x && x <= 149)
```

That will make it work as you expect.

Answer (score 3):

The compiler sees an expression formulated from binary operators. The <= symbol is a binary operator, as are =, >=, ||, &&, and so forth.

Just as with arithmetic, there is an order of precedence that the compiler must follow, evaluating the expression formed around each binary operator.

In arithmetic, you are probably familiar with this, as with these two examples:

2+5*7 This evaluates to 2+(5*7) or 37, because multiplication has precedence over addition.

2+3+21 is evaluated in the order the terms are read from left to right, since there is no other precedence rule. It becomes (2+3)+21.

So 100<=x<=150 is an expression of a similar type, where the binary operators are all the same, and thus have the same precedence. Once again, this is resolved by evaluating it from left to right, so it becomes (100<=x)<=150.  If x>=100 the term in parentheses evaluates to TRUE, which has a numeric value of 1. Since 1 is less than 150, the rest evaluates to 1<=150, or TRUE, if x is greater than or equal to 100. On the other hand, it also evaluates to TRUE if x is less than 100, because the second comparison becomes 0<=150, which is TRUE.

The other recommendations to break this down with parentheses are correct if you aren't sure of the order of precedence for binary operators: (100<=x) && (x<=150). You can also write it as 100<=x && x<=150 since the order of precedence for value comparisons is higher than for logical operators.

Answer (score 2):

Because `if (100 <= x <= 149)` is the same as `if(1<=149)` if you give 200 or another number to x. And that is correct always.

For example.

```
x=1
```

`100<=1` is false so you get `if(0<=149)` which is true

```
x=200
```

`100<=200` is true so you get `if(1<=149)` which is true

So you always get true for it.

So you must do it in another way, like this

```
if(x>=100 && x<=149) ...
```

Comment: Hi there, can you explain that a bit more? Why does it return as (1<=149)? How should I code my statements?

Answer (score 2):

Adding some additional parenthesis may help.

```
if ((100 <= x) && (x <= 149)) //do this
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can write math functions like this in objective-c... Try separating them and combining with an && statement:

```
if ( (100 <= x) && (x <= 149) ) { // "&&" = and, "||" = or, other math comparison operators are: <=, >=, <, >, ==, != (!= is does not equal))
//do this
} else if ( (150 <= x) && (x <= 199) ) {
//do that
} else if ...etc...
```

Comment: Another method used if "&&" operators are too confusing is nested if statements, that's what I started on, but they are very sloppy in some cases. If they ARE ever required I would switch over to "switch" statements. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

You've already got a lot of answers, but I'll add one more to cover one other possible point of confusion.

In C & Obj-C the boolean (and character) types are treated as *integer* types, which is not the case in call languages. So expressions like `'z' * true` make perfect sense!

(Modern) C uses the type `_Bool` for boolean, which is defined to be large enough to hold `0` & `1`. Cocoa uses the type `BOOL` for boolean, which is defined as `signed char`. CoreFoundation uses the type `Boolean` which is defined as `unsigned char`. All three define `YES`/`true` as `1` and `NO`/`false` as `0`, while C itself treats any non-zero value as `true`.

The relation operators such as `<`, `<=` etc. are defined to return the `int` (yes, none of the booleans, not even `_Bool`) value `0` if the relation is false, and the `int` value `1` if the relation is true.

Given this and the left-to-right associativity of relational operators your:

```
if (100 <= x <= 149)
```

is parsed as:

```
if ((100 <= x) <= 149)
```

then `100 <= x` evaluates to the `int` value `1` if `x` is greater than or equal to 100, otherwise it evaluates to the `int` value `0`, so we get:

```
if (1 <= 149)
```

or

```
if (0 <= 149)
```

both of these evaluate to `1` so we get:

```
if (1)
```

and the `if` statement branches to the "then" branch if it's expression is non-zero.

It may be surprising, but the whole statement is evaluated without any use of booleans at all - it is all done with integers.

To achieve what you intended you need:

```
if((100 <= x) && (x <= 149))
```

etc. - which also doesn't use any booleans (`&&` is defined in terms of integers).