# Is (val1 > val2 > val3) a valid comparison in C?

Tags: c

I was messing around a bit in C while making a function, and somehow ended up with a comparison like this:

```
if (sizeAllocated > type_get_binary_size(data) > spaceAvailable)
```

The (for me) unexpected thing was that this compiled without so much as a warning (using IAR compiler for ARM, C99 standard with IAR extensions).
This doesn't look like it should be valid C (at least it's not a valid comparison in any other languages I can think about at the moment), can some gurus help me shed some light on whether this is some IAR-specific quirk or if it's actual standard C that's just too obscure to be included in any common tutorials?

Comment: [Why does (0 < 5 < 3) return true?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4089284/995714), [Language support for chained comparison operators (x < y < z)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4090845/995714)

Comment: I tried searching before posting the question but didn't find those, thanks @LưuVĩnhPhúc! :)

Comment: It is a valid **expression**. Whether it is a valid **comparsion** depends on what you expect it to do.

Comment: You might want to enable more warnings, `gcc -Wall -W` or `clang -Weverything`

Comment: @chqrlie if only I could use GCC or Clang... More warnings might be a good idea though

Comment: You can install `gcc` on a Windows system with `cygwin` or `MinGW`.  You can get more warnings from Visual C++ with `/W4` or something like that.

Comment: @chqrlie "using IAR" - I really wouldn't use a compiler costing several thousand dollars per year (or even windows for that matter) unless I had no other choice, but thanks for the tip anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is valid code, but it won't do what you expect.

The `>` operator is left-associative, so the expression effectively becomes:

```
((sizeAllocated > type_get_binary_size(data)) > spaceAvailable)
```

The inner portion will evaluate to 0 if the condition is false or 1 if the condition is true.  This value is then compared against `spaceAvailable`.

In C, the results of a comparison operator have an integer type, so comparing this result to an integer is valid.

So what you're actually doing is either `0 > spaceAvailable` or `1 > spaceAvailable`, depending on how the first conditional evaluates.

What you probably want is this:

```
int size = type_get_binary_size(data);
if ((sizeAllocated > size) && (size > spaceAvailable))
```

Note that the function call is done first before the `if` so it isn't called twice in the conditional.

Comment: Wow - that's not really what I expected, and you're right about what I intended. IMO that would be a more useful behavior; if I wanted the `((sizeAllocated > type_get_binary_size(data)) > spaceAvailable)` comparison I'd have written it with parenthesis anyway. Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: I suspect OP needs `if ((sizeAllocated >= size) && (size >= spaceAvailable))`  (>= vs >)

Comment: @chux no, `>` was right in this case (not that it would matter to the question though)

Answer (score 2):

The `>` operator is left-associative, so `A > B > C` is *parsed* as `(A > B) > C`.  `A > B` evaluates to 0 or 1, so you're basically comparing `0 > C` or `1 > C`.