# Why does the following inequality evaluate to true in C++?

Tags: c++, operators, inequality, relational-operators

The following piece of code seems so trivial. I don't understand why its not working.

```
float bound_min   = +314.53f;
float bound_max   = +413.09f;
float my_variable = -417.68f;

if (bound_min <= my_variable <= bound_max)
{
    printf("Why on earth is this returning True?");
}
```

Can a C++ wizard of stackoverflow please come and rescue me?

Comment: `bound_min <= my_variable` results in a boolean (in your case `false`) and `false <= bound_max` results in?

Comment: Did you compile that with all warnings and debug info, e.g.  `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g`  with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) ? Did you read [*How to debug small programs*](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) ??

Comment: @t.niese So what would be the "proper" way to evaluate this inequality and make sure that `my_variable` is within bounds?

Comment: Once order of operations is applied, `if (bound_min <= my_variable <= bound_max)` -> `if ((bound_min <= my_variable) <= bound_max)`  and that resolves to `if ((314.53 <= -417.68) <= 413.09)`  and `if ((false) <= 413.09)`. False is 0, so `if (0 <= 413.09)` which is true.

Comment: @user4581301 Thank you for your response and clarification. If you post it as an answer, I would be happy to accept it.

Comment: there are a lot of duplicates: [Language support for chained comparison operators (x < y < z)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4090845/995714), [Why can't I just use 51 <= j <= 55? / data types](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54168808/995714), [100 <= x <= 150 as argument in if (), acting funny](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9014701/995714), [Is (val1 > val2 > val3) a valid comparison in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38643022/995714), [Why do most mainstream languages not support “x < y < z” syntax for 3-way Boolean comparisons?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/316969/98103)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The condition in the if statement

```
if (bound_min <= my_variable <= bound_max)
```

is equivalent to

```
if ( ( bound_min <= my_variable ) <= bound_max)
```

The first subexpression `( bound_min <= my_variable )` evaluates to boolean false.

So as a result you have

```
if ( false  <= bound_max)
```

In this result expression the boolean `false` is converted to the integer `0` due to the integral promotions.

```
if ( 0 <= bound_max)
```

So the final value of the condition is `true`.

From the C++ 17 Standard (8.9 Relational operators)

> 1 The relational operators group **left-to-right**.

```
[Example: a<b<c means (a<b)<c and not (a<b)&&(b<c) —end example] .
```

Answer (score 4):

This is what happens:
First

```
bound_min <= my_variable
```

Then the result (false) used for the next:

```
false <= bound_max
```

Which is true.

And the [reason](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order):

> expression a() + b() + c() is parsed as (a() + b()) + c() due to
>   left-to-right associativity of operator+

Comment: Would it be possible for you to elaborate on your explanation a bit more?

Comment: @AlanSTACK sorry my initial answer was wrong. I edited. is it clear now?