# if number is between two numbers by plus/minus 10 addclass

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

### http://jsfiddle.net/kM8xE/2/

If I have the `div`s
​

```
<div class="value">15</div>
<div class="value2">20</div>​
```

and jQuery

```
var actual = $(".value").html();
var comparison = $(".value2").html();
```

how can i add class `.isbetween` to `.value2` if it's html value is between +/-10 of the html for `.value` ie. for this eg. a value between 5 and 25.

I am not too good but i have tried and it doesn't work.

```
if(parseInt(actual)-10 <= parseInt(comparison) <= parseInt(actual)+10){
$(".value2").addClass("isbetween");
}
```

Comment: The fiddle seems to work, insofar as the `value2` class is highlighted. I read your post a few times and I'm still not quite sure what isn't right (a good rule of thumb: if you have to say "it doesn't work" then rewrite the question. In response to such as statement, people will always say: "what _specifically_ should happen?).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
 if (Math.abs(actual - comparison) <= 10) {
    //they're within 10
 }
```

Comment: .. `comparison.addClass( 'isbetween' );`

Answer (score 3):

The reason this doesn't work is that you can't chain comparisons like this:

```
5 < x < 10
```

In Javascript (and other languages with c-like syntax), you have to make two separate comparisons, and use the *boolean and* operator (`&&`) to chain the comparisons together:

```
var actualValue = parseInt(actual);
var comparisonValue = parseInt(comparison);

if(actualValue - 10 <= comparisonValue && comparisonValue <= actualValue + 10) {
    $(".value2").addClass("isbetween");
}
```

Also, [don't repeat yourself](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).  Do the conversion once, and store it in a local variable.  This makes the code much more readable.

This can be made even more simple by using a concept called [absolute value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_value).  Then you can just do your difference, and see if its *absolute value* is less than or equal to ten.

```
var delta = Math.abs(parseInt(actual) - parseInt(comparison));

if(delta <= 10) {
    $(".value2").addClass("isbetween");
}
```

Comment: Python is the only language I know of where in `5 < x < 10` is the same as `5 < x and x < 10`.

Comment: @DanD.: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4090845/language-support-for-chained-comparison-operators-x-y-z

Answer (score 0):

You have to get the two values, convert them to numbers, compare the absolute value of their difference and then add the class if it meets your condition:

```
var v1 = +$(".value").text();
var v2 = +$(".value2").text();
if (Math.abs(v1 - v2) <= 10) {
    $(".value2").addClass("isbetween");
}
```