# Can I chain comparisons together in an IF statement?

Tags: c++, syntax

I am currently making a naught's and crosses program for college. I have finished the bare bones of this assignment however I am having some trouble creating a win condition to end the game. Below is all of the code I have used so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Player
{
private:
    char NorX;

public:

    char Choose(char InitialValue)
    {
        NorX = InitialValue;
        return InitialValue;
    }

    char GetNorX()
    {
        return NorX;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Player Player1;
    Player Player2;

    Player1.Choose('O');
    Player2.Choose('X'); 

    cout << "The board is being drawn please wait..." << endl;

    const int Rows = 4;
    const int Columns = 4;
    char Board[Rows][Columns] = { {' ', ' ', ' ', ' ' },
                                  {' ', '_', '_', '_' },
                                  {' ', '_', '_', '_' },
                                  {' ', '_', '_', '_' } };

    for (int i = 0; i < Rows; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < Columns; ++j)
            cout << Board [i][j];
        cout << endl;
    }

    cout << endl << endl;

    int row;
    int column;

    do
    {
        do
        {
            cout << "Please enter the value of the row you would like to take ";
            cin >> row;
        }while (row != 0 && row != 1 && row != 2 && row != 3);


        do
        {
            cout << "Please enter the value of the column you would like to take ";
            cin >> column;
        }while (column != 0 && column != 1 && column != 2 && column != 3);


        Board [row][column] = Player1.GetNorX();

        for (int i = 0; i < Rows; ++i)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < Columns; ++j)
                cout << Board [i][j];
            cout << endl;
        }

        /*int row;*/
        do
        {
            cout << "Please enter the value of the row you would like to take ";
            cin >> row;
        }while (row != 0 && row != 1 && row != 2 && row != 3);

        /*int column;*/
        do
        {
            cout << "Please enter the value of the column you would like to take ";
            cin >> column;
        }while (column != 0 && column != 1 && column != 2 && column != 3);

        Board [row][column] = Player2.GetNorX();

        for (int i = 0; i < Rows; ++i)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < Columns; ++j)
                cout << Board [i][j];
            cout << endl;
        }

        if (Board[1][1] == Board[1][2] == Board[1][3] == 'O')
        {
            cout << endl << "Well done you win";
        }

    }while (column != 4 && row != 4);

    system("pause");
}
```

The problem occurs in the if statement as it doesn't seem to have any affect on the running of the program.

Comment: not quite sure you can do that in an if statement, have you tried the long way of `Board[1][1] == 'O' && Board[1][2] == 'O'` ?

Comment: You should prove the problem is in the "if" statement, then post a much shorter and specific question asking how to use "if" properly (if you still struggle after narrowing it down this much).  As it stands, I'm voting to close this as too localized since you are asking what is the problem with your specific code.

Comment: Also notice: array indices are starting at 0, not 1 - and if you want to check for matches in more than one column you have to loop over such an if statement.

Comment: Tried to fix the indentation but can't get Markdown to accept the indendation.  [Bug report filed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/168355/markdown-bug-with-code-indention).

Comment: Please [edit] your code to reduce it to a [mcve] of your problem.  Your current code includes much that is peripheral to your problem - a minimal sample normally looks similar to a good unit test: only performing one task, with input values specified for reproducibility.

Comment: [Language support for chained comparison operators (x < y < z)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4090845/995714)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `if` condition is wrong.
You should replace it with the code below:

```
if ((Board[1][1] == Board[1][2]) && 
    (Board[1][2] == Board[1][3]) && 
    (Board[1][3] == 'O'))
```

When you are checking for horizontal winning condition, all three blocks in the horizontal line must have a value of **0**.

Comment: Thanks for the help it is most appreciated

Answer (score 5):

The result of chaining comparison operators in C++ is not what one expects. The correct way to do this is to connect them with a "logical and" [`&&`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_logical)

```
if (Board[1][1] == 'O' && Board[1][2] == 'O' && Board[1][3] == 'O')
```

---

For the given example

```
if (Board[1][1] == Board[1][2] == Board[1][3] == 'O')
```

you must consider [operator precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence), which is *left to right* for equality operator `==`. This means, the example is the same as (note the additional parenthesis)

```
if ((Board[1][1] == Board[1][2]) == Board[1][3]) == 'O')
```

and works as follows:

```
Board[1][1] == Board[1][2]
```

gives either `true` or `false`. This will be compared to the next part

```
true == Board[1][3]
```

which gives `false`, because `true` or `false` is never equal to a character. This will be compared to the character zero

```
false == '0'
```

which again will result in `false`.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot do this stringing together of comparisons:

```
Board[1][1] == Board[1][2] == Board[1][3] == 'O'
```

All that will happen is `Board[1] == Board[1][2]` is first evaluated to either `true` or `false and then that boolean value is compared to`Board[1][3]` and so on.

What you want is:

```
Board[1][1] == 'O' && Board[1][2] == 'O' && Board[1][3] == 'O'
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use

```
if (Board[1][1] == Board[1][2] && 
    Board[1][1] == Board[1][3] && 
    Board[1][1] == 'O')
```

or

```
if (Board[1][1] == 'O' && 
    Board[1][2] == 'O' && 
    Board[1][3] == 'O')
```

In its current form your statement, for example, compares `Board[1][2]` to the result of `Board[1][3]=='O'` comparsion, not to `Board[1][3]`.

Answer (score -1):

You should run this in a debugger such as gdb.  Google "gdb cheatsheet" to get started.  You will see exactly what lines of code are executing and in particular can verify the "if" is being evaluated.