# Possible to chain comparison operators?

Tags: php, comparison-operators

I've been thus far unable to find this information in the official PHP docs, or on this site.
So, that may mean I'm searching under the wrong terms, or it is not supported.
What am I looking for?
I'll describe it...

Let's say I have the following comparisons in PHP:

```php
if (($a == $b) && ($b == $c))
    doSomething();
else
    doSomethingElse();

if (($d < $e) && ($e < $f))
    doSomething();
else
    doSomethingElse();
```

Does PHP have some kind of syntax to chain the comparisons together without the explicit AND-ing of two different comparisons?
For example, is something like this possible:

```php
if ($a == $b == $c)
    doSomething();
else
    doSomethingElse();

if ($d < $e < $f)
    doSomething();
else
    doSomethingElse();
```

Note that I am looking for a syntactic shorthand in the language.
I know that I can easily write a function for each of these chained comparisons, but this is a kludgy work-around, and not desired.
For example:

```php
function chainedGreaterThan($args)
{
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($args) - 1; $i++)
        if ($args[$i] <= $args[$i + 1])
            return false;
    return true;
}
```

This technically would work, but is not a syntactic shorthand given by the language.

Comment: havent tried it but as dirty as php is, it should work

Comment: No, but come on, why can't you just use `$d < $e && $e < $f`? And, most importantly, what should one do when they are trying to compare the _result_ of `$b == $c` to `$a`?

Comment: @raina77ow How about ($b == $c) == $a? Chained comparison operators aren't that weird. Python and Perl 6 both support it as well, and the notation is very common in basic math.

Comment: @Kevin I'm strongly against using parenthesis to augment the _meaning_ of operator. Here `($b == $c) == $a` will mean one thing - 'compare the result of $b == $c to $a', and `$b == $c == $a` something really different.

Comment: [Language support for chained comparison operators (x < y < z)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4090845/995714)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, PHP doesn't have anything like this.

Comment: Sorry, but I think answer that is just no, should be a comment, its better and looks professional.

Comment: Well, that answers that. Thanks!

Comment: @E.T. its answered also above (second comment under your question!)

Comment: @Akam Comments are not *answers*, and thus cannot be accepted. I chose to accept this answer, instead of copying the two given answers into an answer of my own, since this answer answers the given question, and the other answer answers an un-asked question.

Comment: @Akam, well, then what should the answer be if the question is clearly asking if the thing is possible or not, and it's definitely not?

Answer (score 2):

You could do something awful like this when you have very large amounts of things to compare.

```
<?php
$arr = [1, 2, 3];
$less_than = function($a, $b) {
    return $a < $b;
};
$greater_than = function($a, $b) {
    return $a > $b;
};

function apply_operator($arr, $operator) {
    for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($arr) - 1; $i++) {
        if (!$operator($arr[$i], $arr[$i + 1])) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

var_dump(apply_operator($arr, $less_than)); // true
var_dump(apply_operator($arr, $greater_than)); // false
```

But for greater/less than you can just sort and compare to the original, and for equal you can check the size of `array_unique`.

Comment: Unfortunately, writing a custom function is not a language-supported syntax, it's just a normal function.

Comment: You answered a question that nobody asked.

Comment: @E.T. It *is* “syntax to chain the comparisons together without the explicit AND-ing of two different comparisons”.