# Compound relational operators in C

Tags: c, if-statement, syntax, logical-operators

I am trying to convert a piece of pseudo code into a C code and I have conditions like

```
if (-4 <= X <=8)
THEN {Do Something}
else
{Do something else}
```

Is the syntax in if statement valid? Can a constant be placed before the variable in the logical condition to check the truth value?

Comment: Where did `THEN` come from?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight- I think the OP got this from pseudocode and is trying to translate it into C code.

Comment: it's correct as a grammar, but perhaps different from intention.

Comment: [Language support for chained comparison operators (x < y < z)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4090845/995714), [Why do most mainstream languages not support "x < y < z" syntax for 3-way Boolean comparisons?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/316969/98103)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can have constants as the left hand argument of a logical check in C.

However the pseudocode you have listed would need to be split into two expressions:

`if ((-1 <= X) && (X <= 8))`

Side Note: 
Many developers prefer the "constant on the left" style of logical statement because it will cause a compilation error in certain error-prone comparisons.  For example:
Let's say you wanted to evaluate `if (X == 3)` but accidentally typed `if (X = 3)`.
The latter is a perfectly valid C expression because the assignment operation returns True.
If you were to use the "constant on the left" style:
`if (3 = X)` would cause a compilation error, thus save a lot of time.

Answer (score 8):

In C, you cannot write a condition like

```
if (-4 <= X <= 8) {
     // ...
} else {
     // ...
}
```

Instead, you will have to split this into two separate checks:

```
if (-4 <= X && X <= 8) {
     // ...
} else {
     // ...
}
```

This code is now totally fine - you can have whatever operands you'd like on either side of the `<=` operator.

Comment: Well, technically you can, but it doesn't do what you'd (mathematically) expect. It causes funny situations such as `5 < 12 < 4` being true (`5 < 12` is true, which translates to `1`, so the expression becomes `1 < 4`, which is also true). GCC gives a warning when you try it.

Comment: Note that in some languages (obviously not C) like Python you can do things like `-4 <= X <= 8` and it would have the expected mathematical result.

Answer (score 3):

No; that won't work.

`-4 <= X` is a either 0 or 1, which is always less than 8.

Answer (score 1):

> Is the syntax in if statement valid? Can a constant be placed before the variable in the logical condition to check the truth value?

Not sure if syntax is right, but placing a literal constant before the test for equality\inequality operator is a common practice. Like:

```
if(7==x) {...} else {...}
```

Some programmers do like this, because if you accidentally forget the second '=' symbol in test for equality\inequality\greater then operator, you will receive the assignment of variable to literal, not testing, like:

```
if(x=7) //danger! you're assigning to variable 'x' value of '7',
        //which will return true,  as a side-effect
//now (x==7)==true
```

Also, C language doesn't have 'THEN' keyword, inventors of the language decided that it's redundant - it's obviously easy to understood, that if you have something after if test, then you probably going o execute this code. like

```
if(SOME_MAGIC_CONST==a) 
{
     //There couldn't be anything else at all! else can't follow if immediately, so...
}
else {
     //yep, keyword  'THEN' is redundant...
}
```

Comment: *People do like this*: I personally don't like this, for a variety of reasons.

Comment: Corrected - sure, not everybody doing like this. But this is like a good advice, to secure yourself from stupid mistakes

Comment: Personally I see no reason to write `x==7` if `7==x` is safer.

Answer (score 1):

> Is the syntax in if statement valid?

The syntax is valid, but it won't do what you expect. `<=` is a normal, left-associative binary infix operator in C, so

```
-4 <= X <= 8
```

parses as

```
(-4 <= X) <= 8
```

The result of `<=` is a Boolean value, which C represents as `1` / `0`, and both `0 <= 8` and `1 <= 8` are true.

To get the effect you want (check whether `X` is in a certain range), you need multiple separate comparisons combined with `&&`.

> Can a constant be placed before the variable in the logical condition to check the truth value?

Yes. You can also compare two variables or two constants or pretty much anything.

`<=`, `<`, and all other comparisons are general operators. Their operands can be any expression you want. (Syntactically, that is; for the code to make sense the two operands also must have the same type. `5 <= "abc"` is a type error.)