# Printf even though it shouldn't

Tags: c, if-statement

I have this part of an if statement and I'm getting a weird output.

```
int x = 10;

if(1 < x < 5){
    printf("F\n");
}
```

Why does it print "F"? Logically isn't the if statement false because x is greater than 1 but not less than 5?

Comment: I guess your intention was to determine if the values were transitive (in maths terminology). I did the same thing initially.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Compound relational operators in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17031880/compound-relational-operators-in-c)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C, you can't chain comparisons like that. The expression `1 < x < 5` is evaluated as `(1 < x) < 5`: so for `x = 10`, the expression is `(1 < 10) < 5`. `(1 < 10)` is true, which C represents as the value `1`, so the expression reduces to `1 < 5`. This is always true, and your printf() if executed.

As level-999999 says, in C you need to explicitly combine single comparisons with `&&` and `||`.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using C, you should have broken down the condition into two arguments :

```
    if ( x > 1 && x < 5) {
        printf("F\n");
    }
```

Comment: Isn't it still false in regards to my question?

Comment: Yes. but as @Chogo said. The condition you have set inside the if() might be causing the compiler to misinterpret it.

I have tried coding it with the broken down condition in C, and it did not print anything.

Comment: @Exikle no, the expression you wrote is true regardless of the value of `x`.