# code to print reverse order pattern in c using loops

Tags: c, loops

Here is my code to print reverse order pattern using loops in c:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int i,j;
    i=1;
    while(i<=5)
    {
        j=i;
        while(5>=j>=i)
        {
            printf("%d ",j);
            ++j;
        }
        printf("\n");
        ++i;
    }
}
```

what is the mistake in this code?
I want to print a pattern like:

```
1 2 3 4 5
2 3 4 5
3 4 5
4 5
5
```

but I am getting only this output:
`1 2 3 4 5`

using two for loops:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
  int i,j;
  for(i=1;i<=5;++i)
    {
      j=i;
        for(;j>=i&&j<=5;j++)
        {
         printf("%d ",j);
        }
     printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: `while(5>=j>=i)` if your compiler does not warn you about this, make sure all warnings are enabled, and if it still doesn't warn you, get a new compiler. If you break it into two comparisons your code will work.

Comment: Is there a syntatical error in this statement?

Comment: Yes see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17031880/compound-relational-operators-in-c

Comment: Thanks a lot !!This served the purpose. I got the mistake : ))

Comment: Two `for` loops will create much simpler code... https://ideone.com/6tsEPA

Comment: yeah I did it that way also:

Comment: Please don't post code in comments, edit and post and add an update below your original code.

Comment: oh okay thanks I was trying to figure out that only

Comment: Change `while(5>=j>=i)` to `while(5>=j && j>=i)`, it should work.

Comment: yup thanks it worked this way!! : )

Answer (score 0):

in for loop code  for(;j>=i&&j<=5;j++) , try this for(;j<=5;j++)

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow! Thanks for answering but can you also add an explanation on how your code solves the issue? Also check the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for info on how to format code.