# basic if statement, operator <= undefined

Tags: java

I'm new to programming

```
if( (N%2==0) && (6<=N<=20) )
```

Throws the error below

The operator `<=` is undefined for the argument type(s) `boolean`, `int`
Please help me fix it.

Comment: [Dupe](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4090845/16217248)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't compound the statement like that. You need to `&&` it.

For example,

```
if ((N % 2 == 0) && (6 <= N && N <= 20)) {...}
```

The reason you get the error is the first condition of `6 <= N` resolves to a `boolean` and you then attempt to check if a `boolean` is `<=` to an `int`. That does not compute.

Answer (score 2):

You can't compare 2 conditions in one check, you need to split it to two checks

```
if (N % 2 == 0 && N >= 6 && N <= 20)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should separate the conditions with logical operators (&& in this case):

```
if (N % 2 == 0 && N>=6 && N <= 20)
```