# if-else if-else statement problems

Tags: c

If I write a code like this.It will print 1 obviously.

```
int a = 0;
if (a == 0)
    print("1");
else if (0 < a <= 10)
    print("2");
else if (10 < a <= 100)          
    print("3");
else
    print("4");
```

Then I change the order of the first statement and the second statement, like this.

```
int a = 0;
if (0 < a <= 10)
    print("1");
else if (a==0)
    print("2");
else if (10 < a <= 100)          
    print("3");
else
    print("4");
```

After compile, It still print 1. Why It doesn't print 2 ?

Answer (score 1):

Im not sure what language that is, but many languages don't support chained operator, so you would have break down the comparison like this:

```
 if (0 < a) and (a <= 10);
```

[Language support for chained comparison operators (x < y < z)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4090845/language-support-for-chained-comparison-operators-x-y-z)

Comment: This is exactly what's happening.