# Using multiple logical operator in C not comparing correctly

Tags: c

The following code supposed to print true. But it is printing false. Does anyone know why is it so?

```
int main(void)
{
    int a=15,b=10, c=1;
    if(a>b>c)
    {
        printf("true");
    } else
    {
        printf("false");
    }
}
```

Comment: Those are relational operators, not logical operators, and nobody ever told you they would work that way.

Comment: [Language support for chained comparison operators (x < y < z)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4090845/995714), [Why do most mainstream languages not support “x < y < z” syntax for 3-way Boolean comparisons?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/316969/98103)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C, `a>b>c` means `(a>b)>c`. It does *not* mean `(a>b)&&(b>c)`.

The value of `a>b` is either 0 or 1 (false or true, respectively). Since `c` is 1, neither of those possible values can be greater than `c`, so the comparison is always false.